# Where to get/generate SSL files for new relic postgres integration

Tags: postgresql, newrelic

I am trying to configure new_relic integration to monitor postgresql database connections. One of the configuration options is to either use or not use SSL, and configuration for where SSL files are stored. The documentation does not explain where to get/how to generate these files.

Where can one get, or generate these SSL files?

```
ENABLE_SSL: true
TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE: false
SSL_CERT_LOCATION: <needed postgresql.crt>
SSL_ROOT_CERT_LOCATION: <needed root_cert.crt>
SSL_KEY_LOCATION: <needed postgresql.key>
```

For reference, see: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/infrastructure-monitoring/infrastructure-security/infrastructure-security/

Answer (score 0):

Those are Postgres server-side certificates, and their creation and setup is documented [in the official manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ssl-tcp.html)